# pySerial communication with UART device

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm programming a device like this:
https://wiki.husarion.com/robocore:basics

I'm having trouble connecting to serial port with pySerial. The  serial.tools.list_ports command says no ports found. 
I was using this code to try to connect:

```
import serial
port = 'COM1'

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port=port
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.open()
ser.write(b'q')
ser.close()
```

And it throws this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\serialpy.py", line 7, in <module>
    ser.open()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM1': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
```

I'm running on windows 10.

Comment: Is this in python version 2 or 3

Comment: Can you check the Windows device manager if the serial port is actually there?

Answer (score 0):

I added this in front of my code. It will try to connect to several ports (COM1 - COM10) and pick the first one that is found.

```
import serial

serial_port = False

for k in range(1, 11):

    try:
        port = 'COM{:d}'.format(k)
        serial_port = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
        print(port, 'connected')
        break

    except serial.SerialException:
        print('SerialException')

if not serial_port:

    raise serial.SerialException('not found, but tried hard.')

serial_port.readline()
```